# "cannot currently show desktop"

Tags: ssh, vnc, raspi-config, lxsession

I was working on installing maven on my raspberry pi3b+ and when I rebooted it, it asked me to enter my password again. Upon entering the password a message pops up: Cannot currently show the desktop".

I tried the following but nothing worked:
a) changed the screen resolution to 1280 x 720 and 1920 x 1080
b) installed and reinstalled Lx session
c) booted to desktop mode
d) cleared some space

Comment: this seems like a common error when you use VNC viewer; are you using it? If so, here's some options that might help: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=245158